# Counting permutations without fixpoint

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, ordered-groups

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

Consider an ordered set $S_n = [1,2,3,...,n]$ where the $j$ th element from the left equals $j$.

Now consider a function defined on $S_n$ as a permutation of that set.

$$ f(S_n) = P(S_n) $$

Now iterating the function $f$ means iteratively rearranging the set like the permution $f$ does.

In notation

$$f^m(S_n) = f( f^{m-1}(S_n)) = P ( f^{m-1}(S_n)) = P^m(S_n)$$

--

Let $f$ be a "good" function IFF it does not map any $a$ in $S_n$ to it same position.

Let $G(n,b) $ denote the cardinality of functions $f$ for $S_n$ such that $f,f^2,...f^b$ are all good functions.

What is known about $G(n,b)$ ?

Can it be given in closed form ?

Does it have an integral representation ?

I can not help thinking about binomial and euler numbers but im confused. Maybe this is wrong, maybe not.

This seems to me like a very simple question, so maybe the answer is very well known and the result is named ?

Comment: Sounds to me like you are counting, with $G(n,m)$, the number of $n\times m$ [Latin rectangles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatinRectangle.html).

Comment: No, it has to be less than the number of Latin rectangles since the iteration part is not taken into account.

Comment: My mistake, thanks!

Comment: It looks like Jorge's answer is on the right lines then. For $G(n,m)$ you want to count all permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots , n\}$ with [cycles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationCycle.html) longer than $m$.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good way to look at this is through the cycle representation of the permutation. What we want is the number of permutations such that each cycle has size at least $b+1$.

One possible way to count them is to run through all number partitions of $n$ into parts of size at least $b+1$ (so running through all possible cycle types). For each cycle type we can find the number of permutations with [this simple formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140311/number-of-permutations-for-a-cycle-type).

Iterating through all possible number partitions can be done rather easily if we order them increasingly and go through them lexicographically.

Comment: Im not sure what to think, but it sounds intresting. Im No expert in the stuff you mention...